# How do I reference a local class library project in .NET Core 1.1?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've just started developing with .NET Core 1.1, and I am struggling to see how I can reference a secondary project (e.g. my application's domain/model project) in my primary API project. In previous .NET versions I would have created a class library and referenced it in Visual Studio in the usual way, but I can't seem to see how you could do this in the new framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using CLI(Command Line Interface) write that command :

```
dotnet add "Current/Project/Path/MyProject.csproj" reference "Other/Project/Path/TheOtherProject.csproj"
```

Comment: This cli command is still valid today (.net5)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio 2015, you have to create a package from your class library and put it into a folder which you include as nuget feed to your project the add a dependency in `project.json` to it.

If both are in the same solution, the same applies, but you don't need to manually create a package and set a folder als nuget feed.

If you are using Visual Studio 2017, you can do it same way you did with legacy ASP.NET Applications: Right click the references section, add, browse to the dll and select it. This only works with 2017 and the new VS tooling which uses csproj files instead of xproj ones.

Comment: More precisely it is related to .NET Core SDK. Starting from preview3 MSBuild support is back.

Comment: What about if I'm using VS Code only? I don't think I have any csproj or xproj files in that case?

Comment: @user654081: I never used VS Code so dunno. I think the project.json way still applies for VS Core, so just create a package and make sure do declare the targets (i.e. net45)

Comment: Im using VS2017 I added a refernce to the project (a different project in the same solution) from my asp.net core webapplication but it says type or namespace unknown when trying to use namespaces/classes in the DLL. This works fine for a ASP.NET 4.x MVC app.

Comment: @Paul: You must include the assmebly/project which target the same frameworks. i.e. you can't add .NET 4.5 Project to .NET Core. You must convert it to .NET Standard PCL first. Or your ASP.NET Core project must target .NET 4.5

Answer (score 1):

If your primary project is `xproj`, then it's `project.json` file should look like that:

```
{
  // ...

  "dependencies": {
    // ...        
    "SecondaryProjectName": {
      "target": "project"
    }
  },

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Has .NET Core 1.1 migrated completely to `csproj` now?

Comment: @DerekBeattie, no, it's not.

Comment: Do you know if they be used side by side?  I should probably start a new question for this.

Comment: @DerekBeattie, Microsoft haven't yet implemented design of .NET Core projects in .csproj format. It will become known after release is happened. But I don't see any sense in it, because new .csproj format will replace .xproj completely.